# Rails Query - Join on non-primary column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models: `Foo`, `Bar` and `Profile`. The first two models reference `Profile`.

I would like join Foo and Bar without having to join Profile e.g.

```rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
end

class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
end
```

The SQL would look something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM foo 
INNER JOIN bar ON foo.profile_id = bar.profile_id
```

I could do the following, but I don't want to join `Profile` as it's a much larger table.

```rb
Foo.joins(profile: :bar)
```

Comment: What is `bar` in this context? Currently you post the same `Foo` model twice, was one of these supposed to be `Bar`?

Comment: Hi @engineersmnky, yes it is. Sorry about that.

Comment: Is `Foo` to `Bar` one-to-many or one-to-one or many-to-many? What is the relational dimension here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  def self.join_bars
    bars = Bar.arel_table
    j = arel_table.join(bars)
                  .on(arel_table[:profile_id].eq(bars[:profile_id]))
    joins(j.join_sources)
  end
end
```

You could also just setup an assocation:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
  has_many :bars, 
    primary_key: :profile_id, # the column on this table 
    foreign_key: :profile_id  # the column on the other table
  # or for one to one
  has_one :bar, 
    primary_key: :profile_id, # the column on this table 
    foreign_key: :profile_id  # the column on the other table
end

Foo.joins(:bars)
```

Comment: That second bit is wonderful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using raw SQL query in `joins`.

```
# assuming you have foos and bars tables

Foo.joins("LEFT JOIN bars ON foos.profile_id = bars.profile_id")
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I was hoping for a non-SQL approach. I should have been more clear in the queston.